# The @PropertyMapping annotations @DataJpaTest, @AutoConfigureTestDatabase cannot be used in combination with the @Component annotation @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-boot

I want to create complete JUnit Test with Spring Boot context configuration using Controller and Repository.
My Test class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
//@WebAppConfiguration
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    UserController userCtrl;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext ctx;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(ctx).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void loginTest() throws Exception {
        //mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
}
```

I Have standard User Entity, UserController and UserRepository. I configured my dataSource in application.properties but i can not run @SpringBootTest and @DataJpaTest toogether. This is error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userControllerTest' defined in file [C:\Users\Mateusz\Documents\mojewyceny\target\test-classes\mojewyceny\test\UserControllerTest.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The @PropertyMapping annotations @DataJpaTest, @AutoConfigureTestDatabase cannot be used in combination with the @Component annotation @Configuration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The @PropertyMapping annotations @DataJpaTest, @AutoConfigureTestDatabase cannot be used in combination with the @Component annotation @Configuration
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer$PropertyMappingCheckBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(PropertyMappingContextCustomizer.java:96)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and in particular read the "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Posting a MCVE question will most likely solicit a faster and more useful response.

Comment: @razyel8, can you post your Spring Boot's main class?

Comment: You either want to test the whole Boot application or a slice of it. `DataJpaTest`, `WebMvcTest` and  `JsonTest` are for testing application slices and `SpringBootTest` is for testing the whole application. Don't mix them them together

Comment: I want to test the whole app. But when i remove `@DataJpaTest` my database not working. I've got then: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EmbeddedDatabaseType is required
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EmbeddedDatabaseType is required`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Test class should look like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    UserController userCtrl;

    @Autowired
    public UserRepository userDao;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext ctx;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(ctx).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void loginTest() throws Exception {

        User user1 = new User();
        user1.setEmail("adres@email.com");
        user1.setPassword("12345");
        userDao.save(user1);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/user/login")
                .param("email", "adres@email.com")
                .param("password", "12345"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
}
```

Now it's performing tests on database and handling requests. At the beginning it didn't work, because I was also mixing `@DataJpaTest` and `@SpringBootTest` annotations in other classes